# Apache2 - virtual hosts - 403 Forbidden

Tags: 14.04, server, permissions, apache2

I am trying to set up virtual hosts.

Apache2.4.7

Ubuntu 14.04

*000-default.conf:*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/ronskiy/public_html/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

*test.local.conf:*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName test.local
ServerAlias test.local www.test.local
DocumentRoot /home/ronskiy/public_html/test.local/www/

LogLevel warn
ErrorLog  /var/log/test-error.log
CustomLog /var/log/test-access.log combined

<Directory "/home/ronskiy/public_html/test.local/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

*hosts:*

```
127.0.0.1   localhost test.local
127.0.1.1   ronskiy-K55VM

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

*ls -l:*

```
drwxrwxr-x 3 ronskiy ronskiy 4096 січ 19 23:26 public_html
```

and if I trying to open http://test.local/ I have 403 Forbidden error. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should check the permissions of the folders used as `Document Root` in your configuration. Usually, apache uses the user www-data and you should ensure that this user has the required permissions.

There is a very nice post about this topic here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver

Assuming you are the only one managing the server, this should be a good starting point.

> **Maintained by a single user** 
>   If only one user is responsible for
>   maintaining the site, set them as the user owner on the website
>   directory and give the user full rwx permissions. Apache still needs
>   access so that it can serve the files, so set www-data as the group
>   owner and give the group r-x permissions.

```
chown -R eve contoso.com
chgrp -R www-data contoso.com
chmod -R 750 contoso.com
chmod g+s contoso.com
ls -l
drwxr-s--- 2 eve      www-data   4096 Feb  5 22:52 contoso.com
```

> if you have folders that need to be writable by Apache, you can just
>   modify the permission values for the group owner so that www-data has
>   write access.

```
chmod g+w uploads
ls -l
drwxrws--- 2 eve      www-data   4096 Feb  5 22:52 uploads
```

> The benefit of this configuration is that it becomes
>   harder (but not impossible*) for other users on the system to snoop
>   around, since only the user and group owners can browse your website
>   directory. This is useful if you have secret data in your
>   configuration files. Be careful about your umask! If you create a new
>   file here, the permission values will probably default to 755. You can
>   run umask 027 so that new files default to 640 (rw- r-- ---).